# How to create dynamic routes in electron?

Tags: node.js, routes, electron

How can I create dynamic routes in `electron`? I am confused because `electron` doesn't make use of URLs if am not mistaken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use build in packages such as `express`. The command to install it is: `npm install express --save` (to install locally in the project directory) or `npm install express -g` to install it globally.